# ¿Cómo reusar un JSP como vista para diferentes mapeos de solicitudes en Spring MVC? No plantillas

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Digamos que tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas dento de WEB-INF:

```
WEB-INF
- jsp
  - foo
    + bar.jsp
```

Utilizo el siguiente view resolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

bar.jsp tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> ... </head>
    <body>
        Hola ${nombre}
    </body>
</html>
```

Tengo el siguiente controlador:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class MiControlador {
    @RequestMapping("/bar.html")
    public void muestraBar(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("nombre", "Luiggi");
    }
}
```

Ahora quiero reusar bar.jsp en el mismo controlador pero usando un mapeo de solicitud diferente, de esta manera:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class MiControlador {
    @RequestMapping("/bar.html")
    public void muestraBar(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("nombre", "Luiggi");
    }
    @RequestMapping("/quo.html")
    public String muestraQuo(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("nombre", "Thomas");
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

El método usado arriba fallará porque Spring MVC buscará `bar.jsp` en la raíz, esto es, dentro de WEB-INF/jsp. Quiero/necesito reusar bar.jsp porque básicamente utilizo el mismo contenido, solo con datos diferentes para completar los atributos.

Actualmente, conozco una solución inflexible que es retornar la ruta completa de bar.jsp:

```
@RequestMapping("/quo.html")
public String muestraQuo(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("nombre", "Thomas");
    return "foo/bar";
}
```

¿Existe otra manera de lograr esto?

Nota: No es uso de plantillas. Solo quiero usar el mismo recurso JSP para dos vistas únicamente con URLs diferentes, tal como se muestra en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias detectar dinamicamente el mapeo usado en la URL y en el mismo metodo decidir dentro que datos mandar a tu vista:

```
    @RequestMapping({"/bar.html", "/quo.html"})
    public String muestraVista(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Aqui obtiene el patron usado en la URL
        String patron= (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);

        // patron seria "/bar.html" o "/quo.html", dependiendo de la url requerida
        System.out.println("Patron encontrado: "+ patron);

        if(patron.equals("/bar.html")){
            model.addAttribute("nombre", "Luigi");
        }else{
            model.addAttribute("nombre", "Thomas");
        }

        return "bar";
    }
```

Comment: Por favor revisa el código en tu respuesta (principalmente para otros lectores, no solo para mí): 1) Indica dónde declaras `HttpServletRequest request` y si es injectado o no, 2) la variable `pattern` no está declarada, 3) la comparación de igualdad de cadenas de texto se realiza con `equals` no con `==`, 3) ¿cuál es el uso concreto de `pattern` o `patron` además de usarlo para el `System.out.println` (que debería ser `log.info` o algo similar?

Comment: Ya hice una edicion, tenia algunos errores por escribirlo a las prisas.

Comment: HttpServletRequest se inyecta automáticamente, solo lo declaras en la firma de tu metodo y listo, en el system.out.println solo estoy escribiendo en la consola el patron encontrado para efectos de debuggeo.

Comment: tecnicamente `HttpServletRequest` no se inyecta, lo pasa el servlet a un metodo...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un método genérico para reciclar la vista, como por ejemplo este:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generico", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String generico(Model model) {

    return "bar";
}
```

Y cada vez que llames a una función distinta del controlador retornar un redirect a esta funcion

```
@RequestMapping(value = "bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String bar(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("nombre", "Luigi");

    return "redirect:/generico";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "quo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String quo(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("nombre", "Thomas");

    return "redirect:/generico";
}
```

De esta forma dependiendo de la url entrarás en un método o en otro pero siempre usarás la misma jsp/html

Comment: No quiero un redirect. Quiero usar forwarding. Ten en cuenta que al usar redirect se pierden los atributos del modelo puesto que se inicia un nuevo ciclo de request/response.